# Running a time taking python script on digital ocean

Tags: cloud, digital-ocean

I have a server I lease from Digital Ocean. I access it using Putty in MS-windows 8.1 . I have a dual OS system in which one is Ubuntu 16.04. Now since I am preferred working in my Ubuntu and I have to test a certain python script/code which took around 30 hrs to complete over a certain input data. Keeping my PC on for such a long time is not possible for me. I am thinking of running my code on cloud server like digital ocean . I am new to cloud servers and don't know how to do this or even if this possible or not . I have heard about the term known as 'screen' but don't know how to use this in this situation . Kindly please help me in this issue .

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. If you want to run your Python code in the cloud without having to keep a console or terminal open, then use the [nohup commnad](http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/nohup-command/). This will allow your Python script to run in the background even after you close out of your SSH session. For example, you can run `nohup python script_to_run_in_background.py &` and that should do it.